# How can I calculate the remaining days?

Tags: java, date, datetime

```
private long calculateNextBirthday() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.set(2015, 8, 20);
      //this is birthdate. set it to date you get from date picker

    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    long eta = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long durationMills = eta - now;

    long diffSeconds = durationMills / 1000;
    long diffMinutes = diffSeconds / 60;
    long diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
    long diffDays = diffHours / 24;
    long remainDays = diffHours % 24;


    final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
            - today.getTimeInMillis();

    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated
    // (24 *
    // 60 *
    // 60 *
    // 1000)

    return diffDays;
}
```

This method is supposed to calculate the remaining days for a given date, but
I don't know why this doesn't return the exact value. I think this should return **30** or **31**, but I get **62**.

**Edit:**

I changed my code, but I still don't get the exact value:

```
private long calculateRemainingDays() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2015, 7, 23);
    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
            - today.getTimeInMillis();
    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000;
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Since this calculates the correct value ... what is your question?

Comment: I'm not get exact value...

Comment: Can you work with Java 8? Btw I get 33 days, which are the days _between_ the two dates. You might want to add 1 to get the remaining days.

Comment: Now, the code was working properly. I used c.set(2015, Calendar.JULY, 23) instead of c.set(2015, 7,23). Thank you for your attention. :-)

Comment: `c.set(2015, 7,23)` Sets the calendar to _august_, not _july_.

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting is correct, when you are using 8 for your month you are actually using September, it is indexed at 0. It is better practice to use the built in constants like Calendar.AUGUST, which is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using own code, you code you can use date arithmetic (`Date` API minus along with `DAYS.convert()` ) to find the difference. For populating `fromDate` and `toDate` I used here `SimpleDateFormat`. You may populate `Date` by other means. But the main thing is you need two `Date` to find the difference.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String date1 = "20 05 1985";
String date2 = "22 05 1999";

try {
    Date toDate = dateFormat.parse(date2);
    Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse(date1);
    long diff = toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime();
    System.out.println ("Difference in Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already two answers which either explains why OP's original code didn't work or how he could use `java.util.Date` to solve his question.

I'd like to add a Java 8 version with [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) just to show a more "modern" approach with the newer API.

The `calculateRemainingDays` method can look like this:

```
private long calculateRemainingDays(final Temporal target) {
    final LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    return today.until(target, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

It gets a target [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) and calculates the difference in days from *today*.

This method can be called like this:

```
final LocalDate target = LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 23);
System.out.println(calculateRemainingDays(target));
```

The first line creates a `LocalDate` for the 23<sup>rd</sup> of August 2015(*) and passes it to the calculation method. The result will be printed as ("now" is 20<sup>th</sup> of July 2015):

> 34

It should be noted that the result will be negative if the `target` date is *before* `today`.

---

(*) Note, unlike [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) the months in `LocalDate` are not zero-based, so **8** means "August" and not "September".

Snippet of the JavaDoc of [`LocalDate.of(int, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-):

> *public static LocalDate of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)*
>
> Parameters:
>     *year* - the year to represent, from MIN_YEAR to MAX_YEAR
>     *month* - the month-of-year to represent, from 1 (January) to 12 (December)
>     *dayOfMonth* - the day-of-month to represent, from 1 to 31

If someone is unsure on how to use this method and might get confused about this and the `Calendar` version, then he could use the overloaded version of `LocalDate.of` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-)):

```
final LocalDate target = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.AUGUST, 24);
```

This takes a value from the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum and since it states the name of the month, there can't be a confusion about that.